# Detect powershell function input is redirected

Tags: powershell

I have a subprocess that I want to call from powershell that might be interactive or I might pipe data straight into it. For example:

```
# This is interactive:
& c:\python27\python.exe

# This takes redirected input:
echo hi | & c:\python27\python.exe -c "print repr(raw_input())"
```

I want to create a function that can be used to wrap a call to such a process. I can do this:

```
function python() {
    & c:\python27\python.exe @args
}

# This starts an interactive prompt:
python

# The piped data disappears and the process still reads from the console:
echo hi | python -c "print repr(raw_input())"
```

Or I can do this:

```
function python() {
    $input | & c:\python27\python.exe @args
}

# This doesn't accept interactive input:
python

# The piped data is passed through to the sub-process as intended:
echo hi | python -c "print repr(raw_input())"
```

I cannot figure out how to write a function that handles both cases. If it's invoked without a pipeline, I want it start a subprocess that reads from stdin, and if it's invoked with a pipeline input, I want it to feed that into the subprocess's stdin. Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check value of `$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` expression to find out did your function expect any pipeline input or it is the first element of pipeline.

```powershell
function python {
    if($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput){
        $input | & c:\python27\python.exe @args
    }else{
        & c:\python27\python.exe @args
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define parameter in the function, that will hold your data. Then check if parameter is supplied and act accordingly. You might have to do some tweaking due to the way [how PowerShell passes data to external programs](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right), but the basic idea stands.

Barebone example:

Usage:

```powershell
'foo', '', 'bar' | Invoke-Python
```

Here I'm passing an array to the `Invoke-Python` function.

Result:

- 'foo' will be piped to the python
- Then, function will encounter empty parameter and invoke interactive python
- After you exit the interactive python, the function will pipe 'bar' to the python

`Invoke-Python` function:

```powershell
function Invoke-Python
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        # This parameter will catch your input data
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$InputObject
    )

    # This block runs when pipeline is initialized.
    # It doesn't have access to the parameters,
    # they are not yet parsed at this time.
    Begin
    {
        # Set path to the python
        $PythonPath = 'c:\python27\python.exe'
    }

    # This block runs for each pipeline item
    Process
    {
        # Check, is there anything passed in the InputObject parameter
        if($InputObject)
        {
            Write-Host 'We have some data, let''s pipe it into the python'
            $InputObject | & $PythonPath @('-c', 'print repr(raw_input())')
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host 'No data, let''s just launch interactive python'
            & $PythonPath
        }
    }
}
```